# how to close pandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This feels like (and probably is) a really dumb question, but what do you call to close a dataframe plot that didn't explicitly call matplotlib?

for example, if you type:

```
df.hist(data)
```

Is there a way to close the plot (other than manually clicking on the window's x)?

I'm used to calling `plt.close()`, but is there something similar in pandas? I've tried close & close(), and neither work.

Comment: `plt.close('all')` might just do the trick ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html)). Or if you have normal plots (no subplots as from hist), you can assign them to a variable, e.g. `ax = df.plot.[...]`, then call `plt.close(ax.figure)` to close that plot window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will wait 5 seconds before closing the window:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import time

ax = df.plot()
fig = ax.get_figure()
plt.show(block=False)
time.sleep(5)
plt.close(fig)
```

Alternatively:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
df.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show(block=False)
time.sleep(5)
plt.close(fig)
```