# Close a silent figure opened with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plot multiple figures in `pandas` and save them to a file with:

```
import pandas as pd

for i in range(30):  # loop example
    ax = df.plot(x=date_name, y=metric, legend=False, figsize=(4.5, 3))
    ax.set_title(title, fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'medium'})
    ax.set(xlabel=None)
```

Following [how to close pandas dataframe plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927957/how-to-close-pandas-dataframe-plot), I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close(ax.get_figure())
plt.close(ax.figure)
```

and still get the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:514: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
```

How can I close a silent figure?

Comment: For me putting plt.close(ax.get_figure()) in the cycle worked. Maybe you can try "plt.close('all')" and see if this would work for you?

Comment: You're right and this was my bad. I had another line of code that plotted a figure and  where I forgot to to close. Both commands work to close the plot. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Done, because you already solved your problem, I tried to formulate it in a way that would be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code that you used was OK and should have solved this problem.

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   for i in range(30):  # loop example
      ...
      plt.close(ax.get_figure())
```

2. In case you still face issues after this, try to comment out lines that plot those figures and see if the error remains. If yes, that means that you have some other place that produces those redundant plots.
3. If nothing helped you can try to use plt.close('all') that will close all figure windows.